# Conversión implícita en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio de clase que me trae de cabeza. Tengo que hacer una conversión implícita de unos valores y pasarlos a otros, este es el enunciado:

Conversión implícita. Completa el siguiente programa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

                int num1=5,num2,num3;

                short num4=10;

                char caract='k';

                float num5;  }
```

Realiza las siguientes conversiones y guarda nuevos valores en las variables  correspondientes:

Convierte a int el carácter    caract  ‘k’
Convierte a float el entero    num1    5
Convierte a int el short          num4    10
La salida por pantalla debe ser la siguiente:

El valor de caract es k y ese valor convertido a int es 107
El valor de num1 es 5 y ese valor convertido a float es 5.0
El valor de num4 es 10 y ese valor convertido a int es 10

Tengo solamente esto pero no se seguir a partir de aquí:

```
public class conversion_implicita {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                int num1=5,num2,num3;

                short num4=10;

                char caract='k';

                float num5;

                caract = (int) 'k';
```

Aquí ya no se como seguir, haber si me podéis echar una mano.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Te están pidiendo que guardes en `num1`, `num2` y `char`  lo que hay en `num3`, `num4` y `num5` mediante asignaciones

Comment: Perdona, ese era el ejercicio posterior....fallo, ya lo he arreglado.